# comparing integer value in if statement in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

When I run a `C` program named `anom`, which returns `0` or `1` in a script:

```
while :
do
xentop -b -d 1 -i 50 >> out
cpu=$(tail -n 50 out| tr '\r' '\n' | col -bx | awk '{ total += $4 } END { print total/50 }')
echo "$cpu"
echo "$cpu_before"
det=$(./anom $cpu $cpu_before)
cpu_before=$cpu;
echo "$det"
if [ "$det" -eq "1" ];then
  echo "Detected"
  c=c+1
fi
done
```

It returns this `error` for line  `if [ "$det" -eq "1" ];then` :

```
 [: : integer expression expected
```

and I tried it this way:

```
 if [ "$det" -eq 1 ];then
```

but I get the same error.

Comment: It *returns*, or it *outputs*?

Comment: remove the "" from "$det" .. that becomes a string and -eq expects integers .. check man test

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you get the right value in $det ,

why don't you try

```
if [[ $det -eq 1 ]] 
then
   echo "Detected"
   c=$(($c + 1))
fi
```

The one thing wrong that i see in your code is that you are converting the values into a string before you compare.. and for string we use = operator for comparison.

Comment: **All scalars** in bash are strings. It is the *operator* that decides how the value is interpreted by `[`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams .. the -eq operator expects integers as per the man page .. when we quote the variable it is a string rather than an integer .. imho that was causing the issue... below example shows that quoting converts integers to string ... 
a=1;b=2;
d=$(( "$a" + "$b" )) ## Generates error 
d=$(( $a + $b ))  ## works fine and assigns value d=3  ..

Comment: @NishantShrivastava: It is **always** a string, regardless of quotes. `-eq` tells `[` to *interpret* it as an integer. It doesn't work with `$((...))` because `$((...))` works differently in the first place.

Comment: So why according to you , did '"$det" -eq 1 ' NOT work and why is '$det -eq 1 ' working?

Comment: Because that's not the problem. Or it wasn't the problem. Something else has changed that the asker hasn't told us about or doesn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

The return value from the last command is stored in `$?`. Additionally, commands such as `if` and `while` check the return value of the command invoked for truth (0), allowing you to use them directly.

```
if ! ./anom "$cpu" "$cpu_before" ; then
   ...
fi
cpu_before="$cpu"
```